# UISearchBar disappears from NavigationItem after pushing a view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a `UISearchBar` embedded in the `NavigationItem`, like so:

```swift
let search = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
search.searchBar.delegate = self
search.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
search.definesPresentationContext = false
search.delegate = self
navigationItem.searchController = search
```

And I also have a `collectionView`.

When I push a viewController from the collectionview, and then go back, I can't see the UISearchBar anymore.

Any way of fixing this?

Comment: Try reviewing the [sample app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/displaying_searchable_content_by_using_a_search_controller) provided by Apple.

Comment: How in particular does that sample app intersect this issue @rmaddy?

Comment: @matt The OP isn't setting things up the same as recommended in the sample so doing it the same way may resolve the issue. For example, the OP is missing the call to `definesPresentationContext = true`. The OP is also adding `search.definesPresentationContext = false` which may or may not have an impact.

Comment: `search.definesPresentationContext = false` is certainly wrong. In iOS 13 there is no need to say `definesPresentationContext = true`. However if that's what's wrong with the code why don't we just say that? A link to whole project is not helpful for finding that nugget.